# How to run adb shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb, smartphone

I read an article about fix phone issue but they said run this code to fix.

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.android.setupwizard/.SetupWizardTestActivity
```

From this [Blog here](https://www.virag.si/2015/08/home-button-not-working-after-flashing-to-android-marshmallow/#smooth-scroll-top)

My device is LG G3 (android v5 OS)

So, is there any apk from playstore or google to download to run this command ?

Comment: Use AndroidStudio terminal while your phone is connected

Comment: Do you have android studio installed?

Comment: Yes, I have it, can u provide any link how to do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Windows:

1. Open SDK folder
2. go to platform-tools
3. hold shift and right click
4. click open command window here
5. in command prompt run you commands

Comment: Alternatively cd into the directory

Comment: also alternatively add path to platform-tools in `environment variables` path and use android studio terminal

Comment: I need to instal Android studio or what tools ?

Comment: Ya android studio , If you don't want to install full android studio Then I thing there is program called minimal ADB or something on XDA forums

Answer (score 3):

If you work on `windows` os
open this path in your explorer `C:\Users\YOUR_PC_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools` then press `shift` and right click. then choose `open command window here`. Also you have to enable `usb debugging` on your phone to work with adb commands.